# Add filters dynamically to specific selected properties in table using AngularJS

Tags: angularjs, filter, angularjs-ng-repeat, angular-filters

I have 2 dropdowns one for fields like 'id' , 'name' etc and one for filters like 'uppercase' , 'contains' , 'endWith' etc. Filters value are custom filters name written in angularjs.I have one search textbox where the user types the search item for selected field and property.

```
<div>
    <label>Filter</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedFilter">
        <option value="uppercase">Uppercase</option>
        <option value="startsWithLetter">Starts With</option>
    </select>
</div>
<div>
    <label>Fields</label>
    <select ng-model="selectedField">
        <option value="Id">Id</option>
        <option value="name">startsWithLetter</option>
    </select>
</div>

<input type="text" ng-model="search"/>
```

Now I have writtern a general implementation to fire filter like this

```
app.filter('picker', function ($filter) {
return function (value, filterName) {
    return $filter(filterName)(value);
};
```

});

and few custom filters like this

```
app.filter('startsWithLetter', function () {
return function (items, letter) {
    var filtered = [];
    var letterMatch = new RegExp(letter, 'i');
    for (var i = 0; i < items.length; i++) {
        var item = items[i];
        if (letterMatch.test(item.name.substring(0,1))) {
            filtered.push(item);
        }
    }
    return filtered;
};
});
```

here is the $scope model

```
$scope.friends = [
    {
        id: 1,
        name: 'Andrew'
    },
    {

        id: 2,
        name: 'Will'
    },
    {

        id: 3,
        name: 'Mark'
    },
    {

        id: 4,
        name: 'Alice'
    },
    {

        id: 5,
        name: 'Todd'
    }];
```

I am struggling with a syntax to write in ng-repeat so that filter apply only on that property selected and the selected filter with that search term . if nothing selected then table will show regular data.

```
 <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="friend in friends | filter:{syntax }">
       {{ friend.id}} , {{ friend.name }}
    </li>
</ul>
```

[image]
 I am implementing this feature. Need help?

Comment: try "friend in friends | startsWithLetter : 'A' "... but if you need a variable list of filters, you can create something like "friend in friends | myVariableFilter : myArgs " and populate "myArgs" with conditional parameters

Comment: filter will be based on selected property .

Comment: Suppose user select field : name and filter: startWith and type A in search term how you will map that .
{
        id: 1,
        name: 'Andrew'
    },
{

        id: 4,
        name: 'Alice'
    }

Comment: I will make a jsbin with answer

Comment: thanks waiting for it

Comment: I implement 2 of your 4 filters, to help you... look at: http://jsbin.com/vizowu/edit?html,js,output  Has implemented filter: uppercase and Fields: name... if you select fields: name, you can try it putting the "A" letter on search field

Comment: Here is you are using if condition to check that property suppose later I add more properties like firstname,lastname,email etc then ?
What should be a good approach instead of modifying filter?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/99828/discussion-between-joaozito-polo-and-ghazanfar).